# lazy load module inside main component in Angular 10

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I got two modules in my application one is the `app.module` and another one is `user.module` which gets lazy-loaded. On the `app.module` I got a `sign-in` component, `sign-up` component and `main` component. The `main.component` is the component consisting of a navbar and a sidebar. I want every component inside `user.module` to load inside the `main.component`. But I'm getting error in console `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user/home'`.

[image]

app.routing

```
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './sign-up/sign-up.component';

const routes: Routes = [

      { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'sign-in', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent }
      {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'user',
            loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)
          },
    
        ]
    
      },
      /* { path: '500', component: Error500Component },
      { path: '**', component: Error404Component }, */
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

user.routing

```
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FriendsComponent } from './friends/friends.component';

    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'friends', component: FriendsComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: You will need to share the error, and the full `user-routing.ts` code

Comment: updated..check now. In case you want anything more, let me know and I will create a stackblitz snippet

Comment: See my answer, your code looks ok so I can only assume you are missing the import of `UserRoutingModule` inside `UserModule`

Answer (score 0):

You should import and export the `UserRoutingModule` in `UserModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [..],
  imports: [UserRoutingModule],
  exports: [UserRoutingModule],
  providers: [..]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

everything looks ok, have you specified router-outlet in your main.component.html ?

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```